# Anylogic: sort move to agents in collection based on distance

Tags: anylogic

In anylogic, I have modelled trucks to go to multiple delivery locations. The trucks moves to the first location in the collection using the code

```
moveTo(order.orderLocation.getFirst());
```

After the truck went to the first location, the first agent is removed using the code:

```
  order.orderLocation.removeFirst();
```

The process iterates until the collection is empty (see figure).

I am trying to make the truck go to the nearest agent instead of just the first in the collection. However, I don't know what the code will be to remove the agent that it moved to. I also tried to sort the list based on the distance but didn't succeed. Does anyone know how to model this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step, finding the closest destination, use this:

```
Order theorder= top(orders,x->distanceTo(x));
```

Second step... remove the agent from the population

```
order.orderLocation.remove(theorder);
```

you can also find its index

```
 int index=order.orderLocation.indexOf(theorder);
order.orderLocation.remove(index);
```

If you are more interested in sorting, i would need to know what orderLocation is to make a proper comparator to sort based on distance

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to implement it. I should have given more information on how I modelled it indeed. The variable order (stored in the truck) contains a collection "linkedlist". In this linked list several order locations are stored as type  "Retailer".

Comment: unfortunately the x->distanceTo(x) function doesn't work. Is that due to the choice of collection?

Comment: well "it doesn't work" doesn't give me enough information... but you can look in the help documentation how to use this top function ... ir retailer is your element in the collection, i still don't know what Retailer is... so not much of a help...

Comment: In my model, the retailers are agents placed on a GIS map containing some parameters. I'm sorry, I am not sure what's more to say about it. Hope this info. helps in understand my question.

Comment: well maybe you can do Retailer retailer=top(retailers,r->distanceTo(r)); instead then

Comment: You're a hero. Thank you!